# Delete the respective button

Tags: php

```
 <?php
    include "ludigidb.php";
    session_start();
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) && $_SESSION['user'] == "") {
       header("location:admin.php");
    }
       $db = new luDigi_db ();
       $jk = $db->do_some_magic($db->run_q("select * from emc_leadgen order by emc_time_date desc" ));
       $g=count($jk);
       $colnames =array();
    if (count($jk) > 0) {
    foreach($jk[0] as $k=>$v)
       $colnames[] = $k;
 }?>

<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<html>
<head>
WELCOME <?=$_SESSION['user']?></br>
<a href="logout.php" >log-out</a></br>
<title> emc promo 1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
         <b>the total no rows are :</b><?=$g?>
        <table cellpadding="5" border="1" style="width:450px;"><tr>
<?php   for ($i=0; $i < count($colnames); $i++) { ?>
        <td><?=$colnames[$i]?></td>
<?php   }?>
        <td>DELETE</td>
        <td>EDIT</td>
        </tr>
<?php   for ($i=0; $i < count($jk); $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
<?php   for ($ii=0; $ii < count($colnames); $ii++) {?>
        <td><?=$jk[$i][$colnames[$ii]]?></td>
<?php  }?>
        <td><form action="del.php" method="POST">
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value= <?php echo $jk[$i];?>> 
           <input type="submit" name="downld" value="DELETE" >
           </form></td>
           <td><form action="edit.php" method="POST">
           <input type="hidden" name="id1" value="<?=$jk['$i'];?>">
           <input type="submit" name="downld" value="UPDATE " >
           </form></td>
          </tr>
<?php } ?>
          </table>
          </body>
          </html>
```

As you can see in my program, I'm making a table where all the column names and their respective values are coming. I have also made a delete and edit button. In delete or edit button I'm passing a hidden value, ie `$jk[$i]`.

I solve my problem, now I am passing all the column values to check by this I am able to delete and update user details very easily.

Comment: One tip, non-related but critical: use session_start(); before you include, you must do session_start(); first in almost all situations.

Comment: It sounds like this is something you might want to do with JavaScript.

Comment: no no , this is to be done in php only ...........i really need your anybody help who knows php more than me .............

Comment: I don't think it's possible. PHP is a back-end script that generates logic and in some cases it can generate html that can be viewed on the front end, but you need a front end programming language, like JavaScript, to handle front end events.

Comment: please please rply me fast......................I need your help ......I want to make delete function in which automatically take the ROW_ID and delete the respective row_id